# Stream large models in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have large model of more than 2 million vertices. I want to stream it using three.js from remote URL.
Currently I am using Buffer Geometry for loading it which loads it in one shot.

Is there any loader in three.js which can progressive load model. Any other approach will also work.

I am able to load any type of data(obj, stl or json triangles).

Any kind of suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progressive Loading / LOD / Streaming Mesh in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736353/progressive-loading-lod-streaming-mesh-in-three-js)

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a sort of LOD (level of details) optimization. It really depends on what are you loading.

The usual simple approach in the case of big planar meshes (like terrain) is as follows:

1. split the entire mesh into square pieces;
2. generate several versions of the same square: from highest to lowest
   level of details (thus, number of vertices);
3. serve corresponding squares in appropriate level of details depending
   on the distance form camera, phase of moon or whatever else factor.